# jaspersoft security file issue

Tags: xml, jasperserver

Hello I am trying to implement a new security file on my jaspersoft instance  and am getting the following errors when trying to save my domain. I do not think this is an XML error but possibly something more specific to jaspersoft server when trying to load the file. otherwise i am not sure why this isn't working. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
There is a problem with the security file
The following field(s) can not be found:

The filter condition 'testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_dim_faculty.faculty_username, 'username')' references one or more fields that cannot be found: ID [dw_analytics_dim_faculty.faculty_username].
The filter condition 'testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_dim_graders_rls.grader_username, 'username')' references one or more fields that cannot be found: ID [dw_analytics_dim_graders_rls.grader_username].
The filter condition 'testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_dim_coach.coach_username, 'username')' references one or more fields that cannot be found: ID [dw_analytics_dim_coach.coach_username].
The filter condition 'testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_users_workspaces_rls.username, 'username')' references one or more fields that cannot be found: ID [dw_analytics_users_workspaces_rls.username].
```

here is my formatted XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<securityDefinition xmlns="http://www.jaspersoft.com/2007/SL/XMLSchema" version="1.0" itemGroupDefaultAccess="granted">
   <resourceAccessGrants>
      <resourceAccessGrantList id="JoinTree_1_resource_access_grant" label="aLabel" resourceId="JoinTree_1">
         <resourceAccessGrants>
            <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_1_row_access_grant_faculty">
               <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_FACULTY']}]]></principalExpression>
               <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_dim_faculty.faculty_username,'username')</filterExpression>
            </resourceAccessGrant>
            <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_1_row_access_grant_grader">
               <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_GRADER']}]]></principalExpression>
               <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_dim_graders_rls.grader_username,'username')</filterExpression>
            </resourceAccessGrant>
            <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_1_row_access_grant_coach">
               <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_COACH']} && !(attributesService.getAttribute('tenant','USER')?.getAttrValue().contains('brandman'))]]></principalExpression>
               <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_dim_coach.coach_username,'username')</filterExpression>
            </resourceAccessGrant>
            <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_1_row_access_grant_workspaces">
               <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_COACH','ROLE_FACULTY','ROLE_GRADER']}]]></principalExpression>
               <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(dw_analytics_users_workspaces_rls.username,'username')</filterExpression>
            </resourceAccessGrant>
         </resourceAccessGrants>
      </resourceAccessGrantList>
   </resourceAccessGrants>
</securityDefinition>
```

anyone with jaspersoft experience know what I am doing wrong? Also my Domain has all of the tables listed in the file with all of the joins and references to the `username`.

Comment: Please mind where you put 3 backticks to mark your code blocks, next time you post. It should be put in the separate line (as in edited post) otherwise it will be incorrect;ly rendererd

Comment: thanks @MarcinOrlowski looks like i just messed up on the last part of the code block vs non codeblock. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`so I figured this out, the filter expression reads directly off of your joins from the tables so in some domains in our system the alias of the table read with "dw_analytics..." and in my case it was just the name of the view or table without that. Once I made that change in the xml it was accepted. here is the modified `xml` ```

```
<resourceAccessGrants>
 <resourceAccessGrantList id="JoinTree_1_resource_access_grant" label="aLabel" resourceId="JoinTree_1">
  <resourceAccessGrants>
    
        <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_1_row_access_grant_faculty"> 
            <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_FACULTY']}]]></principalExpression> 
            <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(dim_faculty.faculty_username,'username') </filterExpression> 
        </resourceAccessGrant>
        <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_1_row_access_grant_grader"> 
            <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_GRADER']}]]></principalExpression> 
            <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(dim_graders_rls.grader_username,'username') </filterExpression> 
        </resourceAccessGrant>          
        <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_1_row_access_grant_coach"> 
            <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_COACH']} && !(attributesService.getAttribute('tenant','USER')?.getAttrValue().contains('brandman'))]]>
            </principalExpression> 
            <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(dim_coach.coach_username,'username') </filterExpression> 
        </resourceAccessGrant>      
        <resourceAccessGrant id="Jointree_2_row_access_grant_workspaces"> 
            <principalExpression><![CDATA[authentication.getPrincipal().getRoles().any{it.getRoleName() in ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_COACH','ROLE_FACULTY','ROLE_GRADER']}]]></principalExpression> 
            <filterExpression>testProfileAttribute(users_workspaces_rls.username,'username') </filterExpression> 
        </resourceAccessGrant>          
    </resourceAccessGrants>
</resourceAccessGrantList>
 </resourceAccessGrants>
```